# no gravity for scrollview. how to make content inside scrollview as center

Tags: android, scrollview

I want the content inside the scrollView as center.

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scroller"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingTop="12dp"
    android:paddingBottom="20dp"
    android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
    android:layout_gravity="center" >

    <Button 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="check" 
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"/>

</ScrollView>
```

**Note:** there is no `android:gravity` attribute for scrollvew.

any sol:-

Answer (score 184, accepted):

I had the same issue and finally figured it out. This is for a vertical `ScrollView`.

Put your `ScrollView` inside a `RelativeLayout` and center it in the `RelativeLayout`. In order for this to work, your `ScrollView` should have

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

This is how the final code should look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="b1"/>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="b2"/>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="b3"/>
        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: This one seems to work better for me than the accepted answer. Thank you!

Comment: Ideally android should look into this issues when there is a hierarchy of layout. Also should provide both scrolling(horizontal/vertical) options in one scrollview.BTW thanks @hadi

Comment: This is a bit of a hack, so while this works fine it _feels_ wrong.

Comment: This is ok if you dont need your ScrollView to fill the viewport for some reason. Otherwise its fine

Comment: Hey its working, but doesn't scroll when the keyboard is visible, I tried add in manifest `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize"` but, dont scroll, help me please

Comment: I had problems with the view clipping with the accepted answer.  This method worked for me instead.  I don't know why it behaves like that though, seems like a bug.

Comment: No need to use heavy `RelativeLayout` as root view. It can be `FrameLayout` and `android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"` for `ScrollView`

Answer (score 148):

How about this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingTop="12dp"
    android:paddingBottom="20dp"
    android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay" >


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="check" 
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Yeah! How ABOUT that! This worked fantastically for me, so thank you very much, kind sir.

Comment: There is one problem with this. If you content in the ScrollView is bigger than the scrollview, it will still center it and cut off content at the top (not sure yet why though). Meaning you can't scroll there.

Comment: PatrickBoos is right; this doesn't seem to work. Use hadi's answer below, vertically centering the scrollview in a RelativeLayout.

Comment: Yes, this way have bug, content bigger than scrollView, the content will not scroll to top, his top is negative number, strange :(

Answer (score 104):

I think a more elegant solution would be to use the `ScrollView`'s `android:fillViewport` property. A `ScrollView` is a little different in how it treats it's content view (can only have one), even if you set `match_parent` (`fill_parent`) to the `ScrollView` it won't give that much spacing to it's content view, instead the default behavior is for the `ScrollView` to wrap the content regardless of what you specify for that view. What `android:fillViewport` does is tell the `ScrollView`to stretch its content to fill the viewport (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html#attr_android:fillViewport). So in this case, your `LinearLayout` would be stretched to match the viewport and if the height goes behind the viewport then it will be scrollable which is exactly what you want!

The accepted answer won't work properly when the content extends beyond the `ScrollView` because it will still center the content view first causing it to cut off a portion of the view, and the `ScrollView` centered in another layout works but just doesn't feel right, besides I think it will also result in a lint error (useless parent or something along those lines).

Try something like this:

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scroller"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingTop="12dp"
    android:paddingBottom="20dp"
    android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="check" />

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Just remember that the reason it is being centered here now is because of the `android:gravity` on the `LinearLayout` since the `ScrollView` will stretch the `LinearLayout` so keep that in mind depending on what you add to the layout.

Another good read on `ScrollView` although not about centering but about `fillViewport` is http://www.curious-creature.org/2010/08/15/scrollviews-handy-trick/

Comment: This looks like the most correct implementation, no extra views required.

Comment: Nice solution, seems to be the cleanest one for me. Thanks for it

Comment: Works better than the accepted answer, you saved me a lot of time! Really well done Brian Ethier!

Comment: This is the correct solution, for all the reason described in it.. If you try the solution above, and your scroll view is wider than your screen, you will indeed have part of your scrollview unreachable and be unable to scroll to it... This should be accepted as the proper solution

Comment: Typical Stackoverflow .. the correct solution is often somewhere in the middle.

Comment: Stack overflow should have option to promote correct implementation, other than Vote. This shouldn't be on bottom.

Answer (score 18):

**Use this attribute in ScrollView**

```
android:fillViewport="true"
```

**Example**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
android:fillViewport="true"
>
   <RelativeLayout
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content">

         <!--Your Code goes here-->

   </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

> Make sure to use Single Child in ScrollView just like in above example which is Relativelayout.

Comment: @JoshuaKing may because it is 7 years old question and i posted this answer recently 9 months ago.

Comment: Ha! oh.. truth. Well, it worked perfectly! So thanks!

Comment: This should definitely be the accepted answer! It works perfectly and centers a ScrollView if the content is less than the container size. Works for both ScrollView and HorizontalScrollView. Thank you so much! 

Comment: this can have the unintended effect of stretching your content inside the scroll view

Comment: @martinseal1987 i think effect will depends on your child component, that how you make your layout design, though if this does not work for you, you can make your own custom scroll view component as per your design and work needs. and please also share you desired result screenshot with me, so i can look into and can provide your more better and working solution. ready to help. cheers.

Comment: LIKE  i'd rather use this pram  it so helped

Answer (score 9):

For @Patrick_Boss - what stopped the content from cutting of in my application was to change the gravity and layout_gravity to center_horizontal for the LinearLayout.

It worked for me...but not sure if it will work for you.

Modification of @Ghost's answer -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingTop="12dp"
    android:paddingBottom="20dp"
    android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay" >


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="check" 
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: This solves the cutting the top off problem. But there is still one problem with this solution. The ScrollView content was not centered vertically. But this can be fixed by setting the following values of the ScrollView: android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"

Comment: I have found that for this to work within other layouts, the top ScrollView must be embedded within a FrameLayout.

Answer (score 1):

One thing to consider is **what NOT to set**. Make certain your child controls, especially `EditText` controls, **do not** have the `RequestFocus` property set.

This may be one of the last interpreted properties on the layout and it will **override gravity settings on its parents** (`layout` or `ScrollView`).

Answer (score 0):

using the scroll view inside the ConstraintLayout. It is worked for me

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/white">

            <ScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical" />
            </ScrollView>
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Scroll view height should be wrap_content

```
<ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```